# What would the erb template look like for a ruby enumerator?

Tags: ruby, enums, erb

What would the erb template look like for a ruby enumerator? The answer will be a erb template.

```
require "erb"

# build data class
class Foo < Array

  def build
    b = binding
    # create and run templates, filling member data variables
    ERB.new(File.read('test2.erb')).result b
  end
end

# setup template data


bar = Foo.new([1,2,3])

puts bar.build
```

I would like some way of accessing the 1,2,3 items in the erb template.

Focus on Ruby 1.9.3 compatibility.

Note: the Class is an extension of Array, and I want to access the elements of this array in its erb template.

Comment: I don't know where to start.. to reach the iterator each. Its like Im in an array needing to accessing privates. something like `self`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was as simple as reaching into the self reference.

```
<% self.each{|element| %> <%= element %> <% } %>
```